# JavaFX app: show progress in bar while reading file

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

I have a csv file reader, which calls a method that should update the progress bar. However the progress bar doesn't update, even when I try to schedule it with Platform.runLater. The file reading is part of a synchronous processing so I can't just run the reader in its own thread - I have to wait for the thread to join. The progressbar is working in some other context. What I tried:

```
public CsvFile(File file, SEPARATOR separator)
{
    this.file = file;
    this.separator = separator.value();
    setPattern();

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            readFile();
        };
    };
    thread.start();
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);//HACK
        thread.join();//HACK
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the progress bar method, which is called by readFile():

```
public void setProgressExecute(double progress)

{
    //ProgressExecute.setProgress(progress);
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ProgressExecute.setProgress(progress);
        }
    });
}
```

**Update**

I am now calling `new CsvFile` in it own thread. This makes the progressbar work. However, it also forces me to use Platform.runLater to run GUI updates, since only the JavaFX thread may update certain parts of the GUI. My new problem is with Platform.runLater: it runs stuff in LIFO order which reverses the order of processing. Well I guess you can't have it all.

Comment: What's the point of using a background thread if you're just going to wait for it to complete in the current thread? Your code from `Thread thread = new Thread() { ` up to the end of the `catch` block is essentially equivalent to simply calling `readFile()`.

Comment: Well I was desparate. I thought that if I sleep the thread, maybe Platform.runlater would get a chance to run, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What thread is the `CsvFile` constructor called on?

Comment: I guess the real question is: why are you calling `thread.join()`? What are you trying to achieve with that? It's basically contrary to reading the file in a background thread in the first place. Without knowing what you're trying to do there, it's not really possible to provide a useful answer.

Comment: The CsvFile constructor is called in the javaFX thread.

Comment: So the reason you don't see anything in the progress bar is that you block the FX Application Thread (preventing it updating the UI) by calling `Thread.sleep()` and `thread.join()`). Just remove the `try` block and its contents, and corresponding `catch` block, and you should see the progress bar update.

Comment: Thanks for your help and inspiration. See the update for current status.

Comment: The [documentation for javafx.concurrent.Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) contains a relevant example that should help you.

Comment: "My new problem is with Platform.runLater: it runs stuff in LIFO order which reverses the order of processing". I don't think that happens: the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) explicitly states the opposite ("The Runnables are executed in the order they are posted. A runnable passed into the runLater method will be executed before any Runnable passed into a subsequent call to runLater.").

Answer (score 0):

you can create a service class(LogFilesService extends Service) and bind the progressProperty.
At the Service class you can use the updateProgress to update the progress.